# Reshaping arrays for keras

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I have an array of data which a 2 dimensional array with 3 features :
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]] and I want I reshaped it to fit into keras with a reshape(1,2,3) to have an array like :

```
trainX = [[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]].
```

The training array is nearly the same :

```
trainY = [[4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

I want to pass it to my model. When I pass it like this :

```
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(2,3)))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.fit(trainX, trainY)
```

It says that the number of target samples is not the same as the input samples. There's something I don't understand but I don't know where.

Can you help me ? :D

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
trainX = a.reshape(1, 2, 3)
# [[[1 2 3]  [4 5 6]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a dimension for your labels.

```
import numpy as np
trainX = [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]]
trainY = [[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

np.array(trainX).shape # This equals (1,2,3)
np.array(trainY).shape # This equals (2,3)
```

Depending on how you want to convert, you can do

```
np.array(trainX).reshape(2,3)
```

or

```
np.array(trainY).reshape(1,2,3)
```

Also, your model input_shape is taking (2,3), if you want (1,2,3) you should change it.